# cannot manipulate dom object after nodejs require statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn nodejs and I cannot manipulate DOM object after using the require statement in server.js file. However, it works fine without it. When I click on the paragraph in the browser it would not change. Does anyone know why?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML)</p>

    <script src="server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var config = require('./config');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $("#demo").click(function () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
    })
});
```

Comment: Probably need to look at [requirejs](requirejs.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your server file using node, `document` is not going to reference your browser. Your browser is unavailable to Node. Only front-end javascript is going to be able to reference the DOM. In addition, using `require` in front-end javascript should throw an error if you're not using some bundler such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and therefore the following jQuery code will not run. Open up your browser's developer tools and you should see an error in the console.

Node is not meant to work with the DOM and server files shouldn't be inserted into your HTML. Keep your server code separate from your front-end code. Node is meant to set up servers and serve up files, not to work with the DOM. Try reading more about Node and what it's used for, and maybe do a few tutorials to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the html in the browser, consle say require is not defined
    at server.js:1.  In html script not support the require syntax